# The view connected with IBOutlet property in UITableViewCell can not change frame

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, layoutsubviews

I have a class A , subclass of `UITableViewCell`, and just linked its IBOutlet property `titleLabel` to UILabel in the storyboard. but seems I can not change the frame of `titleLabel`.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.f, 20.f, 100.f, 25.f);
}
```

and also execute the code in `- (void)layoutSubviews` , but not working.

Confusingly when tapped the Cell on the app running in device, the position changed, and I create the `titleLabel` using code, change the frame, then that's all right.

Could anyone help me..

Comment: Check your title label's constraints. Is there any constraints?

Comment: @KenKuan no, I have not added any constants for subviews of the Cell.

Comment: Constraint not constant. And view will auto translate auto resizing mask to constraints for you. Check it runtime with debugger.

Comment: sorry for spelling mistakes， but when tapped the cell, calling `setSelected` method of Cell, then layoutSubview again, it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue as follow :

First add constraints for the view, then connect the constraint properties (Leading, Trailing, Top, Bottom ...) with source files, created the @IBOutlet property variables.

Second modified the value of constrains in the `- (void)updateConstraints`

```
- (void)updateConstraints
{
    [super updateConstraints];
    self.titleLabelHeight.constant = 100.f;
    self.titleLabelLeading.constant = 20.f;
    //...
}
```